# Looping through Countdown

Tags: java, android, loops, countdowntimer

I am trying to loop through a CountDownTimer several times but the problem is the loop finishes before the timer finishes so the countdown only runs once.

function that loops through the timer

```
private void doWorkout(){
    int currentSet = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i<= NUMBER_OF_SETS; i++){
        Log.d(TAG, "doWorkout: iteration " + i);
        startWorkoutTimer();
        //make for loop sleep till timer is done
    }

}

private void startWorkoutTimer() {
    mWorkoutCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(START_TIME, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mWorkRestLabel.setText("Work");
            mWorkRestLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDownText();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mWorkoutTimerRunning = false;
            mButtonStartPause.setText("start");
            mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mWorkRestLabel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            startRestTimer();
        }
    }.start();

    mWorkoutTimerRunning = true;
    mButtonStartPause.setText("pause");
    mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop doesn't wait for the `CountDownTimer` to finish. So it is starting all the timers at once, so it looks like it only ran once.

To fix this, instead of a loop, you have to start a new timer in `startRestTimer()` (which as per your code is in `onFinish()` & runs after a timer is finished) when `NUMBER_OF_SETS` is > 0 and decrement the `NUMBER_OF_SETS`.

So, it will run one after another.

Hope it helps.